# How can i put the Values of a List in a Mysql Database?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to build a GUI with Checkboxes. Then i want put the answers of the checkboxes (0 or 1) i a database. But it has to be dynamically. I can put the answers of the checckboxes in a list.

Now i have the problem that i cant put the list in mysql. I tried it to put the Values of the checkboxes in a String but then i get the error : mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

But when i count the Values i get the equal number of them.

Here ist my code :

```
eingaben = [int_var.get() for int_var in int_vars]
print(eingaben)


Eingabe1 = int(Matrikelnummer_Eingabe.get())  # Alle Eingabefelder müssen in String oder Integer umgewandelt werden
Eingabe2 = int(ID_Eingabe.get())
Eingabe3 = str(VorName_Eingabe.get())
Eingabe4 = str(NachName_Eingabe.get())
Eingabe5 = str(Projektgruppe_Eingabe.get())
Eingabe6 = int(Freigabestufe_Eingabe.get())


test = list()

test.append("ID")
test.append("Matrikelnummer")
test.append("vorname")
test.append("nachname")
test.append("projektgruppe")
test.append("freigabestufe")
print(test)
Attribute = ""
Values = ""
for t in test:
    Attribute += t + ","
    Values +="%s,"
#Attribute = Attribute [:-1]
#Values = Values [:-1]

mList = ""
Values2 = ""
bList = ""
i = 0

for te in Maschinen_Liste:
    bList += str(eingaben[i]) + ","
    i=i+1
    mList += te + ","
    Values2 += "%s,"
    
mList = mList [:-1]
bList = bList[:-1]
print(bList)
print(mList)


Values2 = Values2 [:-1]
ValuesGesamt = Values + Values2
Alle_Spalten= Attribute + mList
print(ValuesGesamt)
print(Alle_Spalten)
print(str(bList))

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Benutzer(" + str(Alle_Spalten)+ ") VALUES (" + str(ValuesGesamt)+ ")"   , (Eingabe1,Eingabe2,Eingabe3,Eingabe4,Eingabe5,Eingabe6,bList  ))
connection.commit()
```

Comment: that depends, savin them in a string yiou have to rewirte the string als the time when something chamges and sql can deal very well with delimitert columns.save every entry in his own row, else you will get later in problems. Also your code is vulnerable to **sql injection** so use **prepared statements with parameters**

Comment: You do realize that when a checkbox is unchecked, it is not sent up in a form submission, right?